# Selecting a field in an ArcGis layer/map in a Nuxt application result in adding legend colorSlider on top of each other in the same div

Tags: vuejs2, nuxt.js, arcgis-js-api

I am using `ArcGis` in a `Nuxt` application. I have got a map with a feature layer (hosted on ArcGis) and a legend with a color slider in the top-right corner. The user can visualise different fields from the layer. For each field selected a new `renderer` is generated and therefore a new `colorSlider`. My problem is that every time the user select a new field, a new colorSlider is added above the previous one and I end up with three coloSliders in the legend. How can I fix that ?? I tried to destroy the previous colorSlider when I select a new field but it seems to destroy the `div` which contains the slider and then I have no slider at all anymore... This is the code =>

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div id="viewDiv"></div>
    <div id="legend"></div>
    <div id="containerDiv" class="esri-widget">
      <span id="title" class="esri-widget">impact legend</span>
      <div id="slider" ref="sliderr"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Map from '@arcgis/core/Map'
import MapView from '@arcgis/core/views/MapView'
import esriConfig from '@arcgis/core/config'
import FeatureLayer from '@arcgis/core/layers/FeatureLayer'
import * as colorRendererCreator from '@arcgis/core/smartMapping/renderers/color'
import ColorSlider from '@arcgis/core/widgets/smartMapping/ColorSlider'

export default {
  props: {
    selectedTab: {
      type: Number,
      default: 1,
    },
  },

  data() {
    return {
      url: 'https://blablabla',
      countries:
        'https://blablabla',
      projectLyr: undefined,
      countryLyr: undefined,
      map: new Map({ basemap: 'osm-light-gray' }),
      view: undefined,
      fieldName: '',
      renderer: {},
      filter: '',
      rendererResult: undefined,
      colorSlider: undefined,
    }
  },

  mounted() {
    esriConfig.apiKey =
      'myApiKey'

    this.projectLyr = new FeatureLayer({
      url: this.url,
      outFields: ['*'],
    })

    this.countryLyr = new FeatureLayer({
      url: this.countries,
      outFields: ['*'],
    })

    this.view = new MapView({
      map: this.map,
      center: [15, 50],
      zoom: 6,
      container: 'viewDiv',
    })

    this.updateLayer({ layer: this.projectLyr, value: 'Impact_PA_area' })
    this.$nuxt.$on('filter-selected', this.updateLayer)
  },

  beforeDestroy() {
    this.$nuxt.$off('tab-selected')
    this.$nuxt.$off('filter-selected')
  },

  methods: {
    generateRenderer(lyr) {
      const colorParams = {
        layer: lyr.layer,
        field: `${lyr.field}`,
        view: this.view,
        theme: 'above-and-below',
      }

      colorRendererCreator
        .createContinuousRenderer(colorParams)
        .then((response) => {
          // Set the renderer to the layer and add it to the map
          this.rendererResult = response
          lyr.layer.renderer = this.rendererResult.renderer
        })
        .then(() => {
          // Construct a color slider from the result of smart mapping renderer
          this.colorSlider = ColorSlider.fromRendererResult(this.rendererResult)
          this.colorSlider.container = 'slider'
          this.colorSlider.primaryHandleEnabled = true
          
          this.colorSlider.viewModel.precision = 1
          this.view.ui.add('containerDiv', 'top-right')

          function changeEventHandler() {
            const renderer = lyr.layer.renderer.clone()
            const colorVariable = renderer.visualVariables[0].clone()
            const outlineVariable = renderer.visualVariables[1]
            colorVariable.stops = this.colorSlider.stops
            renderer.visualVariables = [colorVariable, outlineVariable]
            lyr.layer.renderer = renderer
          }

          this.colorSlider.on(
            ['thumb-change', 'thumb-drag', 'min-change', 'max-change'],
            changeEventHandler
          )
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error('Error: ', error)
        })
    },

    filtering(value) {
      if (value.value.isFilter) {
        this.filter = `${value.value.value}`
        this.projectLyr.definitionExpression = this.filter
      } else {
        this.projectLyr.definitionExpression = `${value.value.value} AND IS NOT NULL`
        if (this.filter !== '') {
          this.projectLyr.definitionExpression = this.filter
        }
        value.isCountry
          ? this.generateRenderer({
              layer: this.countryLyr,
              field: value.value.value,
            })
          : this.generateRenderer({
              layer: this.projectLyr,
              field: value.value.value,
            })
      }
    },

    updateLayer(value) {
      this.$nextTick(() => {
        if (this.selectedTab === 0) {
          this.map.remove(this.projectLyr)
          this.map.add(this.countryLyr)
          this.filtering({ value, isCountry: true })
        } else {
          this.map.remove(this.countryLyr)
          this.map.add(this.projectLyr)
          this.filtering({ value, isCountry: false })
        }
      })
    },
  },
}
</script>

<style scoped>
@import 'https://js.arcgis.com/4.23/@arcgis/core/assets/esri/themes/light/main.css';

#viewDiv {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#containerDiv {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 3px;
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 260px;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just update the `ColorSlider` with the new `ContinuousRendererResult` data instead of trying to destroy/recreate. In a similar way you create it, use `updateFromRendererResult` method to update it ([ArcGIS JS API - ColorSlider](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-widgets-smartMapping-ColorSlider.html#updateFromRendererResult)).